# Asp.net How to get access token within a single post request to a web api controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth

**How to get access token within a single post request to a web api controller?**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using System.Web.Http;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(api_postman.Startup))]

namespace api_postman
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            var myprovider = new MyAuthServiceProvider();
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = myprovider
            };

            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);

            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        }
    }
}
```

> Note here token endpoint path is /token but i want to get access token from my api url using POST request e.g localhost/api/employees

Comment: What have you tryed at this point?

Comment: I wanted to get access token with web api controller at post request